# Thunderbird, DavMail, and Exchange → fetching only Inbox folder?

Tags: linux, thunderbird, exchange

I'm using DavMail with Thunderbird on a Linux client to receive mail via POP3 from an Exchange server.

It seems to work fine (even the calendar part), however all I get is the stuff in the main Inbox. On a Windows machine I use Outlooks's mail filter system to organize my mail into subfolders, and those I don't get via DavMail.

Is this a known limitation/issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meh, I wasn't thinking this through. :-)

Quoting DavMail's [Thunderbird setup](http://davmail.sourceforge.net/thunderbirdimapmailsetup.html) web page:

> There are two ways to access Exchange emails through DavMail Gateway: the good old and efficient **POP protocol, limited to Inbox access** and the IMAP protocol that enables full message folder tree access.

The answer therefore is: switch to IMAP.